# React app on Heroku not serving assets from public directory

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a React web app (with a Flask API backend) that is deployed on Heroku. During development, on localhost, my public assets show up just fine, e.g. the favicon. However, once I've deployed to Heroku, the assets don't show up. The app resolves the requests by returning the index.html page, i.e. instead of returning, say, an ico or png for the favicon, it's returning text/html files.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
client/public/
  index.html
  favicon/
    manifest.json
    favicon.ico
    favicon-16x16.png
    ...
```

And this is how I'm trying to reference them in the `<head>` of my `index.html` file:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon/favicon.ico">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include a `type` in the `<link />` tag. For the .ico file it would be: `type="image/x-icon"`. I'm not clear on what you're trying to do with the manifest file.